# Understanding RxJava method with code not in stream

Tags: rx-java2

I have a function that looks like this:

```
public Flowable<Integer> max(int a, int b){
    // *** Part 1 - start ***
    int max = Math.max(a,b);
    // *** Part 1 - end ***
    return Flowable.defer(() -> {
        // *** Part 2 start ***
        return Flowable.just(max);  
        // *** Part 2 end ***
    });
}
```

When I now subscribe like this:

**EDITED:**

```
max(3,4).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe();
```

1. Will the code from Part 1 run on Schedulers.io()?
2. What are problems that can happen when you write a function like this?
3. What code runs in which thread?
4. What is the difference for part 1 if its not in the stream? Or is it in the stream?

Comment: Code not in the flow is not RxJava. Let me rephrase the question. If you remove all RxJava-related code there, where and when does Part 1 execute?

Comment: When you execute the code without RxJava the function is executed the moment it is called?

Comment: If you start adding RxJava constructs back after that, what part of RxJava or the Java language do you think changes the behavior?

Comment: The behavior changes in the moment the stream is not executed on the main thread (asynchronous operations). Otherwise It will just work fine?

Comment: So you think the moment RxJava appears in the code you showed, suddenly part 1 executes on some other thread?

Comment: Thats is what I want to know.

Comment: Or does it mean the code gets executed the moment the function is called and only the value gets returned when you subscribe to the stream?

Comment: Can't you just try your code and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I now subscribe like this:

That code doesn't subscribe, you have to call `subscribe()`.

> Will the code from Part 1 run on Schedulers.io()?

The code in `max()` runs as soon as it is invoked on some thread: it calculates the max and creates a `Flowable` capturing the bigger value.

> What are problems that can happen when you write a function like this?

Part 1 executes on the caller thread which may not be what you wanted. At that point, RxJava isn't even involved.

> What code runs in which thread?

`max()` runs on the caller thread and nothing else gets executed.

> What is the difference for part 1 if its not in the stream? Or is it in the stream?

Part 1 is out of the stream. You have to put those computation into the stream via `fromCallable` for example, although such trivial operations may not be worth putting into a stream.

```
public Flowable<Integer> max(int a, int b){
    return Flowable.fromCallable(() -> 
        // *** Part 1 - start ***
        Math.max(a, b)
        // *** Part 1 - end ***
    );
}

max(3, 4)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(v -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
        System.out.println(v);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. And sorry, I forgot the subscribe(); (That was intended to be there and I will add it to the question) Sure such a trivial function doesn't make sense but I needed a simple example to explain main question.

Answer (score 0):

Will the code from Part 1 run on Schedulers.io()?

Ans: Part one will run on main thread or caller thread. As you didn't put it under the rxjava method.

What code runs in which thread?

Ans: part 2 runs on caller thread. It may be main thread or a new worker thread.

What is the difference for part 1 if its not in the stream? Or is it in the stream?

Ans: It is out of the stream. You may get output from it. But that didn't depend on rxjava.

Use All code inside the rxjava method. Otherwise stream flow may differ. This type of simple calculation can be used on main thread. use rxjava when working with database or rest api call.

Comment: If you call that method from main thread then yes it is from main thread. Or if you call that method from a working thread then it will be executed under that working thread and then below code will create an extra working thread to execute further code.